# fatal error: boost/version.hpp: no such file or directory on Wndows

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, g++

[Error on Git Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ureFg.png)

Hi, me and my tutor are working on a ML software that requires C++ and boost library (version >= 1.68.0). I have boost 1.78.0 installed in C:. When I try to run the software under the correct directory (C:\Admin\Desktop\smartspec\scenario-generation) with the given code `g++ -std=c++17 entitygen.cpp -o entitygen` or `make entityGenCompile` I get the error on the screenshot. The file does exist, the path exist, there is everything to make it function but it just doesn't and it's quite frustrating. We didn't find anything helpful on the net, I'm using Windows 7 by the way.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to include the Boost directory in your include search path (`-I /c/boost-1.78.0` or similar as per your directory structure). By default includes are only looked for in the "usual" places (`/usr/include` etc.). As opposed to `PATH` which can easily be expanded, there is no such "system search path" for includes.

Comment: Please include the error message as text in the question. An external image can disappear...

Comment: Also, it is not quite clear what your environment is. Make sure that the Boost libs you installed match the compiler you are using! C++ libraries are compiler-dependent. If you use a MinGW g++, you need MinGW Boost. If you use a Cygwin g++, you need Cygwin Boost.  And so on.

Comment: @DevSolar thank you! How do I know if my boots is matching MinGW (I use that not Cygwin)?

Comment: @AriannaCollarile: You either compiled Boost yourself -- in which case it automatically matches your compiler. Or you did download Boost from some source. That source will tell you if those binaries are meant for MinGW (which would always be specified explicitly), or just "Windows" (which usually means Visual Studio).